# Copying information from a separate workbook in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy the information from cells A2 to A4 into my current workbook and am using the following code to do so, however, when I run the macro I get the message: Run-time error '9', subscript out of range. How do I make it in the range?

```
Application.Workbooks("Client and Project Droplist").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A4").Select
Selection.Copy

Me.Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

*UPDATE*

I've made it so that it will select the range but now I am getting run-time error 13: Type mismatch. Here is the new code

```
Private Sub Macro_Click()
Application.Workbooks("Client and Project Droplist").Activate
Application.Workbooks("Client and Project Droplist").Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
Application.Workbooks("Client and Project Droplist").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A4").Select

Selection.Copy

Workbooks("VBA Exercises").Worksheets(Sheet1).Select
'Workbooks("VBA Exercises").Worksheets(Sheet1).Range("A1").Select
'ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

I commented the last two lines because I haven't quite gotten there yet.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  It looks like you have to specify the actual filename, and when you tried to paste it to your active workbook, it wasn't truly active.

```
Application.Workbooks("client and Project Droplist.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A4).Select
Selection.Copy

Application.Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select
Selection.Paste
```

Comment: You forgot quotes on your (Sheet1)